# XAML unhadled exception

Tags: xaml, exception, windows-store-apps, windows-10

I have windows store application. On old systems it worked but now when I run my application on Windows 10 I get strange error

*System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect.
Failed to get pointer input transform history.
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control.OnPointerMoved(PointerRoutedEventArgs e)*

Inner exception is null and I don't know how to resolve this issue. Do you have any tips how do explore source of unhandled exceptions in WPF? Because I have any clue which from my huge amount of controls can cause this error.

Comment: Are you by chance using webview anywhere? I'd start there if so.

Comment: Create a sample application which demonstrates the exception and provide it in your post.

Comment: @ChrisW. yes this exception is happened when I go back from View containing WebView. But I don't any clue why it is working on windows 8 and not on windows 10 and what can can cause this exception

Comment: @OmegaMan unfortunately, it is not possible to create sample aplication because it is too complex

Comment: I would advise a *divide an conquer* way of determining where the fault actually resides. Comment out each of the primary sections until you have a working app. Then re-add the sections until one can narrow down the issue.

Comment: What is the stack trace? If this is for Windows Store, it isn't a WPF error.